# iis7 integrated windowsauthentication prompts for username and password

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7

I am using asp.net application in vs 2008
I need to use windows authentication in iis7. i have set up windows authentication in web.config and enabled windows authentication in iis. I disabled anonymous authentication.
when i browse localhost,it is asking username and password.

For localhost it should not ask for username and password.

Any idea

Thanks

Comment: My guess is that you're configuring Windows authentication at the "web site" level.  You probably want to do it at the web application level

Comment: Is the server a member of a domain?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IE, then enable windows integrated authentication from tools --> internet options -- advanced tab.
Also when you access the site, see which zone it is going to. If it is going to internet, single sign on may not work. So you have to add the site to your intranet zone by going to tools --> internet options --> security tab --> local intranet --> sites --> advanced --> type the URL such as http://yoursitename.test.com and click add
Also make sure tools --> internet options --> security tab --> local intranet --> custom level --> authentication --> automatic logon only in intranet zone option is selected

Also Kerberos will never work on local machine. You have to try from remote machine in the network.

Good luck.